# How to populate multiple sql select statement in a dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have sql like:

```
select employee_name, employee_id from employees;
select admin_name, admin_id from admin;
```

Yep! we all know how to populate an sql query in a dropdown list but what I am looking for is on how would I possibly populate the data of this two sql in a single dropdown ?

Does anyone have a magical idea ? BTw, I'm using c# asp.net and even open to use jquery, json or the like to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN to combine these 2 queries.The number of columns and datatype of corresponding columns in each queries must be same.

```
select employee_name as name, employee_id as id from employees
UNION
select admin_name as name, admin_id as id from admin
```

you can use 'name' as textfield and 'id' as value field

If you are trying to create dropdown data using this query,there may be a problem of identifying admin and employees seperately(both may have same id)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. But sir, I dont need a join or a union since the tables that I'm about to use has no linked column or an FK. I just need  both columns to be populated in a single DD. like i'll have :

john<--empployee name
mark<-- admin name

in a drop down. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

To get both table data in single query, you should put `union` between both tables. Column names from both tables should same also. For that you can use column aliasing.

```
(select employee_name as name, employee_id as id from employees)
Union all
(select admin_name as name, admin_id as id from admin);
```

You can bind data from this query to your drop down list.

Hope it work for you.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. But sir, I dont need a join or a union since the tables that I'm about to use has no linked column or an FK. I just need both columns to be populated in a single DD. like i'll have : john<--empployee name mark<-- admin name in a drop down. Thanks

Comment: For this case to use **Union**, no need of linked column or FK. This query is only to populate both columns of given tables. 1 condition is column name should be same, which can be achieved using column aliasing.